# Is it possible to match any character that is not ']' in PATINDEX?

Tags: t-sql

I need to find the index of the first character that is not `]`. Normally to match any character except `X`, you use the pattern `[^X]`. The problem is that `[^]]` simply closes the first bracket too early. The first part, `[^]`, will match any character.

In the documentation for the [`LIKE` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx), if you scroll down to the section "Using Wildcard Characters As Literals" it shows a table of methods to indicated literal characters like `[` and `]` inside a pattern. It makes no mention of using `[` or `]` inside double brackets. If the pattern is being used with the `LIKE` operator, you would use the `ESCAPE` clause. `LIKE` doesn't return an index and `PATINDEX` doesn't seem to have a parameter for an escape clause.

Is there no way to do this?

(This may seem arbitrary. To put some context around it, I need to match `]` immediately followed by a character that is not `]` in order to locate the end of a quoted identifier. `]]` is the only character escape inside a quoted identifier.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible. The Connect item [PATINDEX Missing ESCAPE Clause](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/259534/patindex-missing-escape-clause) is closed as won't fix.

I'd probably use CLR and regular expressions.

A simple implementation might be

```cs
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlInt32 PatIndexCLR(SqlString pattern, SqlString expression)
    {
        if (pattern.IsNull || expression.IsNull)
            return new SqlInt32();

        Match match = Regex.Match(expression.ToString(), pattern.ToString());
        if (match.Success)
        {
            return new SqlInt32(match.Index + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return new SqlInt32(0);
        }
    }
}
```

With example usage

```sql
SELECT  [dbo].[PatIndexCLR] ( N'[^]]', N']]]]]]]]ABC[DEF');
```

If that is not an option a possible flaky workaround might be to substitute a character unlikely to be in the data without this special significance in the grammar.

```sql
WITH T(Value) AS
(
SELECT ']]]]]]]]ABC[DEF'
)
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^' + char(7) + ']%', REPLACE(Value,']', char(7)))
FROM T
```

(Returns `9`)